# How can I make the (EditText) automatically send the user to the other page if the input is correct? without need button. android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, if-statement, android-edittext

I'm doing a graduation project, and I need your help guys !
I use Android Studio ..
And I needed a way to make the field EditeText do action after entering the correct password

and the Action is : move the user directly to another page.
without need to press a button.
i try this code and nothing happen

```
pass= findViewById(R.id.password);
pass.addTextChangedListener(enter);
    }
    private TextWatcher enter = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            //EditText.OnEditorActionListener
           if(pass.getText().toString().trim()=="123123"){
             Intent intent = new Intent(log_page.this,Casher.class);
               startActivity(intent);
               }
           }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            String passAccount= pass.getText().toString().trim();
            if(pass.getText().toString().trim()=="123123"){
                Intent intent = new Intent(log_page.this,Casher.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in java to check strings with each other to see they are equal or not you need to use `equals` method instead of `==` because `==` this will check for their references for string and objects:

```
if(pass.getText().toString().trim().equals("123123")){
    Intent intent = new Intent(log_page.this,Casher.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much it's working now ! You helped me a lot thank you again